# lose connection with amazon ec2 VM

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I lose connection with my Amazon EC2 VM.  I think the reason is that I have configured the wrong route table rules, but is there any other way to login to the VM to see what actually happened?

Using get system log I get some information, but I also noticed that at the bottom there is this line:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.1 (Maipo) 
Kernel 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 on an x86_64
ip-172-31-30-157 login:
```

I wonder if I can use this to login into the VM, but the username is ec2-user? What is the password? I usually use `ssh -i` without password!

Answer (score 0):

I'm reticent to approach this question without knowing the actual error you are seeing.

The system is definitely booting according to the system log output you've provided.  That means it's either a routing issue or transport issue.

Please update this with the connection informatin/command/tool you are using and the error you are getting back.

Since you think it's a route issue, does this EC2 have a public IP address?  Does it's subnet route to a VPC Internet Gateway?  Are you able to ping the instance or connect to it with any other protocols?